# ggplot2 - getting 'scale_fill_identity' to create a legend, labelled with a different attribute

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using R to make a graph of NFL data, showing the weekly cumulative yard totals for the top-10 NFL receivers.
I have a dataset (`rec_leaders`) with columns including:
`week`, `playername`*,* `yardtotal` (as of that week), and `teamcolour`.

My code so far is as follows:

```
rec_leaders |> 
  ggplot(aes(x=week, y=szn_total, color=teamcolor, group = playername) ) +
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point() +
  scale_fill_identity()
```

This code produces this graph: [Cumulative Yards for Top-10 Receivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZIwJ.png)

I'm struggling to add a useful legend. If I use the "guide= 'legend' " arg for scale fill identity, it produces a legend showing the colour codes; I want to show the playernames instead. [(Graph with Bad Legend)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88GMt.png)

I'm aware I can specify the labels manually, e.g. `scale_color_identity(labels=c("a", "b", "c", ...),  guide='legend')` . Can I get the legend label names to automatically populate from the data's 'playername' attribute.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated - thanks in advance!

Tried playing around with label options in scale_color_identity(labels=c("a", "b", "c", ...),  guide='legend').

I can't find a way for the labels to automatically populate from the attributes of the data, ensuring that there's still a connection.

Comment: The default approach would be to use a named vector of colors, e.g. `pal_color <- dplyr::distinct(rec_leaders, playername, teamcolor) |> tibble::deframe()`. Then map `playername` on `color` and apply the color palette using `scale_color_manual(values = pal_color)`.

Comment: Is this really your code? You never assign `aes(fill=)` yet you're using `scale_fill_identity`, I didn't know it could work like that ... (and I can't get it to work)

Answer (score 0):

As @stefan said, the preferred/canonical approach is to use a "natural" (legend-friendly) variable within `aes(fill=)` and then use `scale_fill_manual(values=..)` to relate the natural name with the preferred color.

An example using `mtcars`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
mt <- mtcars |>
  transform(
    cyl_word = ifelse(cyl == 4, "Four", ifelse(cyl == 6, "Six", "Eight")), 
    literal_color = ifelse(cyl == 4, "red", ifelse(cyl == 6, "green", "blue"))
  )
head(mt, 3)
#                mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb cyl_word literal_color
# Mazda RX4     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4      Six         green
# Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4      Six         green
# Datsun 710    22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1     Four           red
```

(Yes, there are many other ways to make that example dataset.)

Your approach:

```r
ggplot(mt, aes(mpg, disp, color = literal_color)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_identity()
```

[image]

And now you're stuck trying to add a meaningful legend.

Instead, let's let `ggplot2` manage the colors first, and then we'll override them later.

```r
ggplot(mt, aes(mpg, disp, color = cyl_word)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values = c(Four = "red", Six = "green", Eight = "blue"))
```

[image]

There are better ways to manage the colors and the data with them. For instance, I might prefer to maintain a separate frame with `cyl_word` and their colors, and join them in. I'll create the aux frame, and then revert to the original `mtcars` to show my use of it:

```r
cyl_colors <- data.frame(cyl = c(4, 6, 8), cyl_word=c("Four", "Six", "Eight"), color=c("red", "green", "blue"))
cyl_colors
#   cyl cyl_word color
# 1   4     Four   red
# 2   6      Six green
# 3   8    Eight  blue

mtcars |>
  merge(cyl_colors, by="cyl", all.x=TRUE) |>  # left-join
  ggplot(aes(mpg, disp, color = cyl_word)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_color_manual(values=with(cyl_colors, setNames(color, cyl_word)))
```